# First line and last line in jtextarea viewport

Tags: java, swing

i am looking for a function which gives the viewport starting line and viewport ending line from jtextarea.  The below code works fine.  But when the number of lines in the jtextarea is too big, say 10,000 lines, response of the cursor becoming very slow.  I narrowed down the line which is causing it, it is,

```
 startLine = getRow(topLeft, editorTextArea) - 1; //editorTextArea is jtextarea name
 endLine = getRow(bottomRight, editorTextArea);
```

I am calling the startAndEndLine() on every keyPressEvent

Can someone suggest me a better code, which is efficient?

```
private void startAndEndLine() {

    Rectangle r = editorTextArea.getVisibleRect();
    Point topLeft = new Point(r.x, r.y);
    Point bottomRight = new Point(r.x + r.width, r.y + r.height);

    try {
        startLine = getRow(topLeft, editorTextArea) - 1;
        endLine = getRow(bottomRight, editorTextArea);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
       // System.out.println(ex);
    }        
}


 public int getViewToModelPos(Point p, JTextComponent editor) {
    int pos = 0;
    try {
        pos = editor.viewToModel(p);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return pos;
 }


public int getRow(Point point, JTextComponent editor) {
    int pos = getViewToModelPos(point, editor);
    int rn = (pos == 0) ? 1 : 0;
    try {
        int offs = pos;
        while (offs > 0) {
            offs = Utilities.getRowStart(editor, offs) - 1;
            rn++;
        }
    } catch (BadLocationException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return rn;
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do with said information? I suspect that there is a more efficient way to do whatever you are trying to do with the information retrieved from this code.

Comment: @thatidiotguy the content of the textarea is sent to a class along with the first line and last line numbers for doing custom validation

Comment: Thats a lot of lines especially to be shown all at once on your TextArea to be honest Im surprised you never got a JVM max heap error... So basically its normal for it to be slow. Not thta it cant be sped up a little though. Why have so much text on the jTextArea at a time? why not only load whats needed and load the rest as necessary

Comment: If you are sending the content of the textarea why don't you just send it as a String? Why does it need the whole Swing object?

Comment: @thatidiotguy i am sending to that class only the string not jtextarea.  I am using the above mentioned code to get the starting line number and ending line number that has to be valuated.

Comment: @DavidKroukamp i did not get heap error.  It it essential to show all the lines as the lines are interconnected for validation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is based on a solution by JigarJoshi from this question [Java: column number and line number of cursor's current position](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5139995/java-column-number-and-line-number-of-cursors-current-position) ... You gotta love this site ;)

```
protected int getLineNumber(int modelPos) throws BadLocationException {

    return textArea.getLineOfOffset(modelPos) + 1;

}

Rectangle viewRect = scrollPane.getViewport().getViewRect();

Point startPoint = viewRect.getLocation();
int pos = textArea.viewToModel(startPoint);

try {

    int startLine = getLineNumber(pos);

    Point endPoint = startPoint;
    endPoint.y += viewRect.height;

    pos = textArea.viewToModel(endPoint);
    int endLine = getLineNumber(pos);

    System.out.println(startLine + " - " + endLine);

} catch (BadLocationException exp) {
}
```

This is not entirely accurate, but gives you a starting point.